# Table data into Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

An Accounting Table has the sample data shown below:
(There could be more AcctgHeads than those shown here)

```
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Loan  | AcctgHead | Amount | D_C |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
|     1 | Principal |  10000 | D   |
|     1 | Principal |    500 | C   |
|     1 | Cash      |  10000 | C   |
|     1 | Cash      |    500 | D   |
|     2 | Principal |   5000 | D   |
|     2 | Cash      |   5000 | C   |
|     2 | Cash      |    300 | D   |
|     2 | Principal |    300 | C   |
|     1 | IntDue    |     50 | D   |
|     1 | IntIncome |     50 | C   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

The desired ouput is:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Loan | Principal_D | Principal_C | Cash_D | Cash_C | IntDue_D | IntDue_C | IntIncome_D | IntIncome_C |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    1 |       10000 |         500 |    500 |  10000 |       50 |        0 |           0 |          50 |
|    2 |        5000 |         300 |    300 |   5000 |        0 |        0 |           0 |           0 |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

What would be the query to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (assuming your acctghead has fixed number of values as shown)

```
select loan, 
isnull(Principal_D,0) Principal_D,
isnull(Principal_C,0) Principal_C,
isnull(Cash_D,0) Cash_D,
isnull(Cash_C,0) Cash_C,
isnull(IntDue_D,0) IntDue_D,
isnull(IntDue_C,0) IntDue_C,
isnull(IntIncome_D,0) IntIncome_D,
isnull(IntIncome_C,0) IntIncome_C
from 
(select loan, amount, AcctgHead + '_' + D_C As AcctgHeadDC from t) t
pivot
(
       max(amount) for AcctgHeadDC in
       (Principal_D,Principal_C,Cash_D,Cash_C,
        IntDue_D,IntDue_C,IntIncome_D,IntIncome_C)
) p
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95ee4/5)